# Saving list of items from directory into collection

Tags: groovy

I need help with saving list of files into collection.

```
def collection = {
new File("/path/to/directory/").listFiles().sort { it.name }.reverse().each { def f ->
    println f.name
 }
}
```

This one is only printing result I want to have in collection

result that i want:
list = [file1.jpg, file2.jpg, file3.jpg]

On the internet I found only recursive methods, but those dont fit to my code.

Answer (score 3):

You may define the *closure* this way

```
def collection = {
new File("/path/to/directory/").listFiles().sort { it.name }.reverse().collect { f -> f.name
 }
}
```

and `call` it to fill the collection

```
def lst = collection.call()
```

Alternatively you may directly populat ethe collection with

```
lst =   new File("/path/to/directory/").listFiles().sort { it.name }.reverse().collect { f -> f.name }
```

Comment: For golfing: `.collect { f -> f.name }` can be `*.name`